# Android Emulator crashes with custom high resolution

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have created a profile with 1125 x 2436 and 5.8" diagonal (xxhdpi). 2GB RAM Android Q 9+ on a Windows 10 machine with Android Studio 3.4.2. 
Other default high resolution profiles work fine.

Once I start this I get following console error on both Software and Hardware render.

```
6:22 PM Emulator: *** BUG ***

6:22 PM Emulator: In create_bits_image_internal: The expression bits == NULL || (rowstride_bytes % sizeof (uint32_t)) == 0 was false

6:22 PM Emulator: Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug

6:22 PM Emulator: 

6:22 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted an emulator with 2280x1080 and dpi 411, but the emulator only supports a fixed set of dpi values.

So I scaled the screen size to something based on a supported density - 400dpi - and got 1051x2218 but that caused the same error as above.

```
emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized

*** BUG ***
In create_bits_image_internal: The expression bits == NULL || (rowstride_bytes % sizeof (uint32_t)) == 0 was false
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug

emulator: emulator_window_fb_rotate
```

The 'rowstride bytes' part suggested to me that the width needs to be a multiple of 4 bytes (sizeof uint32).

So I changed my width to 1052 (which is divisible by 4) and the error went away.